# Error while compiling Inkscape from source code

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, inkscape

Not having well knowledge on dealing with C++ projects, I have downloaded the source code of [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) from its [GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape) and made few changes (adding small feature) and tried to compile based on the instruction provided in [INSTALL.md](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and other sources available on their website.

While it seems I have all the dependencies installed on the system, I get this result after running cmake in build folder:

```
------------------------------
Building Makefile for Inkscape
------------------------------
Source Dir: /home/user/myProgs/inkscape
Binary Dir: /home/user/myProgs/inkscape/build
-- Creating build files in: /home/user/myProgs/inkscape/build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found GTest: /usr/lib/libgtest.so  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for modules 'harfbuzz;pangocairo;pangoft2;fontconfig;gsl;gmodule-2.0;libsoup-2.4>=2.42'
--   
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:415 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:588 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeScripts/DefineDependsandFlags.cmake:42 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:136 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/myProgs/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/myProgs/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The relevant lines in DefineDependsandFlags.cmake:42 are:

```
pkg_check_modules(INKSCAPE_DEP REQUIRED
              harfbuzz
              pangocairo
          pangoft2
          fontconfig
          gsl
          gmodule-2.0
          libsoup-2.4>=2.42)
```

As far as I checked, all these packages are already installed on my system.

Here is the content of [CMakeError.log](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/sdrx) in which these lines might gives some clue:

```
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_d21be.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_d21be -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d21be.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_d21be' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_d21be] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/myProgs/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_d21be/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_d21be/fast] Error 2
```

I couldn't find any help from searching in Internet.
Any help would be appreciated.

---

I have tried compilation on both Kubuntu 17.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Are the development packages for those libraries installed as well? The library packages themselves do not provide the C/C++ header files required to compile against them.

Comment: Also: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads` -- The library is `pthread`, not `pthreads`.  This looks like a typo in the makefile.

Comment: @cdhowie as far as I checked using grep, there is nowhere calling -lpthreads. [see this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25492618/)

Comment: Perhaps you can grep for `pthreads` instead of `-lpthreads`.

Comment: The `pthreads` error is irrelevant, it is standard CMake check. It searches for the right flag name, on some systems it is `-pthreads`.

Comment: Run `pkg-config` with all packages that inkscape require, and make sure it outputs right flags for each of them.

Comment: @arrowd Which packages exactly I should check? Those seven packages that was mentioned in the question? (harfbuzz, pangocairo, pangoft2, fontconfig, gsl, gmodule-2.0, libsoup-2.4>=2.42) and how exactly? For example running `pkg-config libharfbuzz-bin` which I think is related to Harfbuzz, return nothing.

Comment: Is there any possibility or resolving this issue if I compile on a 32-bit system? Can it make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some missing dependencies you need to install in order to compile the source code. According to your cmake results:

```
A required package was not found
```

The easiest way in Ubuntu (Kubuntu tested) is to install Inkscape development packages from the ppa repository. Type the following command in terminal then hit Enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/trunk
```

After that you need to enable source code repository. Try to uncomment `deb-src` line. (Remove # from the beginning):

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/inkscape_dev-ubuntu-trunk-zesty.list
```

- **Note** that you can use your favorite text editor instead of vim.

Now update the list of packages using `sudo apt update`. Next you're ready to install the development packages:

`sudo apt build-dep inkscape-trunk`

Now it's all set to compile and run ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved the problem. I added the PPA before. The only think I didn't do was to uncomment `deb-src`. I compiled the project with no error now.