# Packages missing while compiling Inkscape source code on Windows with MINGW64

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, inkscape

I am trying to compile the source code for Inkscape following this guide https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Compiling_Inkscape_on_Windows_with_MSYS2

I get the following errors

```
    -- Checking for modules 'harfbuzz;pangocairo;pangoft2;fontconfig;gsl;gmodule-2.0;libsoup-2.4>=2.42    
    --   No package 'harfbuzz' found                                                                      
    --   No package 'pangocairo' found                                                                    
    --   No package 'pangoft2' found                                                                      
    --   No package 'fontconfig' found                                                                    
    --   No package 'gsl' found                                                                           
    --   No package 'gmodule-2.0' found                                                                   
    --   No package 'libsoup-2.4' found
```

I found this answer [Error while compiling Inkscape from source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124197/error-while-compiling-inkscape-from-source-code) but that only works for Ubuntu and I am working on Windows.

I ran this script

```
msys2installdeps.sh


# install Inkscape dependencies (required)
eval pacman -S $PACMAN_OPTIONS \
$ARCH-double-conversion \
$ARCH-gc \
$ARCH-gsl \
$ARCH-libxslt \
$ARCH-boost \
$ARCH-gtk3 \
$ARCH-gtkmm3 \
$ARCH-gdl \
$ARCH-libsoup

# install Inkscape dependencies (optional)
eval pacman -S $PACMAN_OPTIONS \
$ARCH-poppler \
$ARCH-potrace \
$ARCH-libcdr \
$ARCH-libvisio \
$ARCH-libwpg \
$ARCH-aspell \
$ARCH-aspell-en \
$ARCH-gtkspell3

# install ImageMagick (as Inkscape requires old version ImageMagick 6 we have to specify it explicitly)
# to prevent future updates:
#     add the line
#        "IgnorePkg = mingw-w64-*-imagemagick"
#     to
#        "C:\msys64\etc\pacman.conf"
#     or (always!) run pacman with the additional command line switch
#        --ignore=mingw-w64-*-imagemagick
for arch in $(eval echo $ARCH); do
  wget -nv https://gitlab.com/ede123/bintray/raw/master/${arch}-imagemagick-6.9.10.69-1-any.pkg.tar.xz \
    && pacman -U $PACMAN_OPTIONS ${arch}-imagemagick-6.9.10.69-1-any.pkg.tar.xz \
    && rm  ${arch}-imagemagick-6.9.10.69-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
done


# install Python and modules used by Inkscape
eval pacman -S $PACMAN_OPTIONS \
$ARCH-python3 \
$ARCH-python3-pip \
$ARCH-python3-lxml \
$ARCH-python3-numpy \
$ARCH-python3-pillow \
$ARCH-python3-six \
$ARCH-python3-gobject

PACKAGES="coverage pyserial scour"
for arch in $(eval echo $ARCH); do
  case ${arch} in
    mingw-w64-i686)
      /mingw32/bin/pip3 install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager ${PACKAGES} || \
      /mingw32/bin/pip3 install --upgrade ${PACKAGES}
      ;;
    mingw-w64-x86_64)
      C:/MinGW/opt/python3/Scripts/pip3 install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager ${PACKAGES} || \
      C:/MinGW/opt/python3/Scripts/pip3 install --upgrade ${PACKAGES}

      ;;
  esac
done
```

The script downloads and installs Inkscape's dependencies.

Comment: "But that didn't help" does not provide any information. Does this script  download something? Produces any error message?

Comment: @Pedro you're right that is ambiguous and unhelpful I edited the question with some of the script.  The rest of it selects whether it compiles to i686  or x86_64

Comment: Please ask this question in the Inkscape developer chat, either via IRC #inkscape-devel on freenode, or via our rocket.chat instance at https://chat.inkscape.org/channel/team_devel . I'm surprised libsoup isn't installed, maybe it's just the wrong version? Our automated builds work, but maybe Windows version plays a role etc. Edit: Or make an issue at https://inkscape.org/report .

Comment: I think the reply in the chat was something like running a specific command repeatedly. Did that work?

Comment: Just tried it but no change I updated the chat on it thanks for checking @Moini